# WCF Username Password security with wshttpbinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have written a WCF service with custom user name and password security. When i added the service reference in the same project it is working as expected. I have used self signed certificate for this service. When i am trying to add service reference in another solution through local IIS i am getting the following error. This is same while browsing the .svc file from local IIS.

Exception:

> The authentication schemes configured on the host ('IntegratedWindowsAuthentication') do not allow those configured on the binding 'WSHttpBinding' ('Anonymous').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly.  Additionally, this may be resolved by changing the authentication schemes for this application through the IIS management tool, through the ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the application configuration file at the  element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding, or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the HttpTransportBindingElement.

Comment: Insert your config into the post by editing it.

Comment: Can you please post your code / config. Your question is very useful for me, I am trying to set wsHttpBinding with username / password, but I don't know where to set username.